# How I add a class css to php?

Tags: html

```
function autoDate()
{

    for ($i = 1; $i <= date("t"); $i++) {
        echo "<li>" . $i . "</li>";
        if ($i == date("j")) {
???
   }
    }
}
```

I need to put class "active" when date of today is true...

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not extend the output accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should code here:

```
function autoDate() {
     $data = "";
     for ($i = 1; $i <= date("t"); $i++) {
        $data .= "<li>" . $i . "</li>";
         if ($i == date("j")) { 
           $data .= "<li class='abc' >" . $i . "</li>";   
         }
     }
    echo $data; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to add the active class to the list, then you should do that before you echo your list:

```
function autoDate() {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= date("t"); $i++) {
        echo "<li" . ($i == date("j") ? ' class="active"' : '') .  ">" . $i . "</li>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function autoDate()
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= date("t"); $i++) {
        $class = '';
        if($i == date("j")){
            $class = 'active';
        }
        echo "<li class='".$class."'>" . $i . "</li>";
    }
}
```

Try this one.

by default `$class` is empty and if date matched then `$class = 'active'`

Comment: What's the error. I executed and it works fine.